# How to calculate arc length

Tags: circles

I forgot my secondary school maths, so I need to ask to confirm.

Arc Length = Radius*(Angle In Radian)

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: This might be enlightening: http://www.mathwarehouse.com/trigonometry/radians/s=r-theta-formula-equation.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This works because $C = 2\pi R$ and, coincidentally, there are $2\pi$ radians in one full rotation. Clearly, a fraction of a full rotation produces a fraction of circumference.

To be fair, your equation is in fact the definition of radian.

Answer (score -1):

It's approximately correct only because you assume that the arc is the base of a triangle... It only works where you can say that sin(θ) is approximately θ. For small angles only.
General solution using $sin^{-1}$ is also an approximation tho because of the curvature.
If it was me, I would calculate the perimeter with the given Radius and calculate the ratio corresponding to the ratio $\frac{360}{\theta}$.

Comment: 1 radian is the arclength equivalent to the radius of the circle, by definition.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian

Comment: Oh... My bad...